# QMediaPlaylist supported formats

Tags: c++, qt, documentation

I'm trying to find a list of supported playlist formats for QMediaPlaylist. But I can't find it in the documentation here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplaylist.html or anywhere else.

I would be glad if somebody can point me to where I can find this info. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From Qt's doc referenced lower:

> "For most features, Qt Multimedia builds upon the multimedia framework
>   of the underlying system."

So supported formats will rather depend on the multimedia backend used (which depend on your platform), rather than the QMediaPlaylist. Have a look here:

https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.5.0_Multimedia_Backends

Comment: Thank you, that would work if the PlaylistFormat plugins section would not be empty there :).

Comment: @Stvad so you're talking about the playlist format itself, ex .m3u, .pls (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playlist#Types_of_playlist_files), as opposed to the file/streams format listed in this playlist? Then indeed, sorry, can't help :)

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about Playlist formats :)